# Unittesting the cancellation of a retrofit call

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit, android-mvp

I'm trying to write a unittest that tests a cancellation of a Retrofit call, but I'm stuck.

Here's the implementation:

```
public class LoginInteractorImpl extends AbstractInteractor implements LoginInteractor {

    private volatile Call<ResponseBody> mCall;

    private UserRepo mUserRepository;

    @Inject
    public LoginInteractorImpl(WorkerThread workerThread, MainThread mainThread,  UserRepo userRepository) {
        super(workerThread,mainThread);
        this.mUserRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void login(final String username, final String password, final OnLoginFinishedListener listener) {
    mWorkerThread.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCall = mUserRepository.doLogin(Credentials.basic(username, password));

                enqueue(new LoginCallbackImpl(mWorkerThread, mMainThread, listener));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        if(mCall != null) {
            mCall.cancel();
        }
    }

    void enqueue(LoginCallback callback){
        mCall.enqueue(callback);
    }
}
```

Here's what I've got so far in my testclass:

```
public class LoginInteractorTest {

    private LoginInteractorImpl mLoginInteractor;

    @Mock
    UserRepo mockUserRepository;

    @Mock
    private Call<ResponseBody> mockCall;

    @Mock
    private LoginInteractor.OnLoginFinishedListener mockLoginListener;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mLoginInteractor = new LoginInteractorImpl(new FakeWorkerThread(), new FakeMainThread(), mockUserRepository);
    }

    ...

    @Test
    public void shouldCancelLoginCall() throws Exception {

        final String username = "test";
        final String password = "testtest";

        LoginInteractorImpl spy = Mockito.spy(mLoginInteractor);

        when(mockUserRepository.doLogin(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(mockCall);

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // Somehow delay the call and cancel it instead?

        when(mLoginInteractor.enqueue(any(LoginCallback.class)))
            .thenAnswer(
                // Somehow pospone the call from executing
            );

        // Enqueue logincall
        mLoginInteractor.login(username, password, mockLoginListener);

        // Cancel call
        mLoginInteractor.cancel();

        // Verify that cancel was called
        verify(mockCall, times(1)).cancel();
    }
}
```

My question is how can I stop the mockCall from being executed and verify that I've succeeded in doing my cancelation? My best bet is that I somehow have to use CountDownLatch, but I've never used it before and haven't been able to find and answer anywhere on how to use it in my usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
public void shouldCancelLoginCall() throws Exception {

    final String username = "test";
    final String password = "testtest";

    LoginInteractorImpl spy = Mockito.spy(mLoginInteractor);

    when(mockUserRepository.doLogin(anyString())).thenReturn(mockCall);

    doNothing().when(spy).enqueue(any(LoginCallback.class));

    mLoginInteractor.login(username, password, mockLoginListener);

    mLoginInteractor.cancel();

    verify(mockCall, times(1)).cancel();
}
```